# *ngIf for all sub routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-ng-if

I want do figure out how I can show a container with *ngIf for all sub routes.

Like for:

```html
<div *ngIf="router.url === /page/**"></div>
```

So this container is shown when I am at "page" and also for all subpages of "page".

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public currentLink: string;

    constructor(private router: Router){

        this.currentLink = this.router.url;

   }
   if(this.currentLink.startsWith('/page/')) this.flag = true;
   else this.flag = false;

  <div *ngIf="flag"></div>

> you can get the URL using observable also
```